# multiple strings as argument in table input

Tags: kettle

I'm trying to use SQL like select column from table where column in (?)
as ? should be concatenation of strings. I did script, that concatenates rows in something like 'string','secondstring' and so on.
I know, I should use just more parameters, but to the moment of execution I don't know, how many arguments there will be, and that is hundreds of them each time.
I'd like to do it in one SQL, so putting every argument in a single row, and check "execute for each row" isn't perfect either.

Any clue, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the cycles and variables kettle.
For example:**

-create a job that contains:

1)a transformation where you store in an environment variable 
(`setVariable ("varname" value, "r")` r is the parameter to be accessible by the parent job) the concat all input rows.

2)a transformation which makes the desired query with variable replacement (`SELECT column FROM table WHERE column IN (${varname})`).

If you need I can send the example files.